# Jenkins + sonar-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins, sonarqube

Anybody know how to change/define the source directory for sonar-maven-plugin? I've tried to define parameters -Dsonar.source=/src/main/scala -Dsonar.test=/src/test/scala but these are not applied when the plugin starts on jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You have to change those parameters in the POM itself. Trying to "override" those parameters with "sonar.*" properties won't work when running Sonar analyses with Maven.